Help Getting NFS Through UFW Firewall on Ubuntu Server
I have a local server. Specs below
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

I had set up the NFS file system, and it worked for months. However, I just realized I failed to enable the UFW firewall. I did so, and these are the current rules of UFW
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2049                       ALLOW IN    192.168.5.0/24            
2049                       ALLOW IN    192.168.5.249             
8096/tcp                   ALLOW IN    192.168.5.0/24            
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    192.168.5.0/24            
111                        ALLOW IN    192.168.5.0/24  
Unfortunately, I can no longer connect to my NFS server, and I cannot figure out why. If I disable the UFW firewall, I can connect again, so I know the issue is with the firewall. Can anybody help please?
RPCinfo results:
rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  60077  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  40319  mountd
    100005    2   udp  47683  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  35457  mountd
    100005    3   udp  43621  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  50491  mountd
    100024    1   udp  43570  status
    100024    1   tcp  33041  status
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100021    1   udp  40469  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  40469  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  40469  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  35909  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  35909  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  35909  nlockmgr


For NFSv4 what you've done should be sufficient - however if you need to support earlier protocol versions you will probably want to choose a fixed mountd port and allow that as well - see for example nfs is blocked by ufw even though ports are opened
